# EmberJS router connectOutlets firstObject binding doesn't seem to propagate

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

Seem to have an issue with bindings when accessing an associated DS.model to DS.model `array.firstObject`. So the path in the fiddle below is `App.person.parties.firstObject` but it doesn't seem to bind properly. `App.person.parties` is bound OK and can be used in the outlet but `firstObject` never seems to work. Any ideas?

Also I don't think this is the best approach for `nextParty` - if anyone could offer some advice on how to structure this it would be much appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/mJ7q7/5/

JS: -

```
/* Flip this switch to compare. You should see 'Ember party' appear after 2s when it works */
var works = true;

window.App = Em.Application.create({

    ready: function() {            
        App.set('person', App.store.find(App.Person, 1));                        
    },

    ApplicationView: Em.View.extend({templateName: 'application'}),
    ApplicationController: Em.Controller.extend(),

    Router: Em.Router.extend({

        root: Em.Route.extend({

            index: Em.Route.extend({

                route: '/',
                connectOutlets: function(router, context) {

                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('dashboard', App.get('person'));
                    router.get('dashboardController').connectOutlet('nextParty', 'party',
                        App.get('person.nextParty')
                    );
                }
            })
        })
    }),

    DashboardController: Em.Controller.extend({}),

    DashboardView: Em.View.extend({
        templateName: 'dashboard'
    }),

    PartyController: Em.Controller.extend({}),
    PartyView: Em.View.extend({
        templateName: 'party'
    }),


    Party: DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr('string') 
    }),


    Person: DS.Model.extend({
        firstName: DS.attr('string'),
        lastName: DS.attr('string'),
        parties: DS.hasMany('App.Party'),

        nextParty: function() { return this.get('parties.firstObject'); }.property('parties.firstObject')
    }),




    store: DS.Store.create({
        revision: 7,
        adapter: DS.Adapter.create({

            find: function(store, type, id) {



                if (type == 'App.Person') {

                    if (works) {

                         store.load(type, id, {
                            id: 1,
                            firstName: 'John',
                            lastName: 'Jackson',
                            parties: [99]   
                        });

                    } else {

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            store.load(type, id, {
                                id: 1,
                                firstName: 'John',
                                lastName: 'Jackson',
                                parties: [99]   
                            });
                        }, 1000);

                    }

                }
                if (type == 'App.Party') {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        store.load(type, id, {
                            id: 99,
                            name: 'Ember party'  
                        });  
                    }, 2000);                            
                }
            }
        })
    })

});
```

Templates: -

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>Party app</h1>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dashboard">
    <h2>Hi {{content.firstName}} {{content.lastName}}</h2>
    <h3>Next party</h3>
    {{outlet nextParty}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="party">

    {{content.name}}

</script>    ​  ​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `firstObject` and `lastObject` properties are not bindable. You can circumvent it by creating a computed property:

```
myFirstObject: function() {
  return this.get('content.firstObject');
}.property('content.[]')
```

See [here](http://codebrief.com/2012/03/eight-ember-dot-js-gotchas-with-workarounds/).